# Exporting data from HDFS to MYSQL using sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to export data from `HDFS` to `MySQL`. I tried below code and it throws error but I when executed `select *` query in MySQL table I was able to see 56 records out of 115 records. Below is my code:

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampleOne \
--username root \
--password root \
--table SAMPLEDATA \
-m 2 \
--export-dir /sampleData.csv \
--update-mode allowinsert
```

Presence or absence of last `update-mode` line doesn't make any difference.

ERROR MSG:

```
18/04/21 20:23:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 9
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=1
        Killed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=2
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=13910
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=13910
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=13910
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=14243840
18/04/21 20:23:22 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
18/04/21 20:23:22 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 23.5885 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
18/04/21 20:23:22 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
18/04/21 20:23:22 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
18/04/21 20:23:22 ERROR mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Export job failed!
18/04/21 20:23:22 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: 
Export job failed!
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:445)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.exportTable(SqlManager.java:931)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Can anyone explain me where am I going wrong?? Thanks in advance

Comment: How many nodes in the Hadoop cluster? More than 1? If so, `-m 2` with `jdbc:mysql://localhost` will only import half the records, as seen

Comment: I am working on single machine. So in this case how many mappers should I use ? I tried with increasing the number of mappers but it didn't helped me

Comment: In that case, I suggest opening the YARN UI to inspect the actual error message of the failed map task, or set mappers to 1

Comment: tried with one mapper but in vain even I tried to go through the logs but its very confusing. Can you just help how to track error in that log. Its a very lengthy log file.

Comment: You go to `localhost:8088`, then hit the log for the sqoop application, then find the log for the failed map. One of the links will says either `stderr` or `syslog`, and that's where the error should be

Comment: Yeah i couldn't find anything specific to this error. Can you please post some code which I could try or modify in my existing code ?? or share some links which i can refer

Comment: There is no "code" here to upload... And the Sqoop documentation is all I would link to... Your Sqoop command looks fine, you just need to find the actual error message of the mapper task, not only the sqoop job

Comment: Okay let me try my luck with the official documentation

Comment: Okay so when I referred log I discovered that there was problem with my input data. I deleted header in my data file as it was string and ID is of INT datatype and I executed my query again. Everything works smoothly now. Thanks for your help though @cricket_007 :) . Have a good day !

Comment: Cool. Feel free to provide your answer below rather leave it in the comments